# ODBC Connection Time out didn't fire

Tags: c#-4.0, odbc

I'm trying to connect my asp.net application to an Informix DB using ODBCconnection.
The problem that I'm facing is if the Informix Db is down, my application takes forever trying to establish the connection.
It seems that the ConnectionTimeout doesn't work for me..

The following is the code that is used.

```
private string StartTimerForTest()
    {
        string err = "";

        OdbcConnection odbc_Conn = new OdbcConnection();
        odbc_Conn.ConnectionTimeout = 1;

        DataTable ConnDt = new DataTable();
        FormDataTable(ref ConnDt);
        LoadSagaConfig(ref ConnDt);
        SetOdbcConnectionstring(ref odbc_Conn, ref ConnDt);

        try
        {
            odbc_Conn.Open();
            odbc_Conn.Close();
        }
        catch (OdbcException ex)
        {
           err = ex.Message;
        }

        return err;
    }
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: is any exception thrown at all?  Like network error?

Comment: no, but it will eventually but after 3 sometimes 5 or sometimes 10 minutes. What i would like to do is for the code to stop after 3 seconds and return an error. normally, it takes less than a second if the db is up and running normally.